# Rich Text And Images In VisualForce

Tags: visualforce, apexrest, richtextarea

If i create a richText inside of a visualforce page and i paste a screenshot inside the rich text box .

1. Is it Possible to bind the whole rich text content to a 'string ' in the controller,
2. Will the screenshot image be serialized/ encoded accordingly

The reason is that , im hoping that i can send a rich text as part of an HTTP request  to another endpoint (which is basically a salesforce apex rest service)

Comment: images won't be UTF-8 so you would need to bind to a controller variable of type `Blob`

Comment: Yes i got that part. But something i have just discovered too is that it is not possible to Paste a screen shot inside a visualforce rich text area. If one wants to add an image , then you need to specify the image Url which is not exactly what i want to achieve. I want to be able to paste the image/screenshot , and then send that image as part of the request